# create 2 branches from develop to implement 2 features

Tags: git, git-branch

I follow this [git workflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow)

I clone the project in the folder **myproject** and checkout the develop branch:

```
git clone the_remote_url myproject
git checkout develop
```

I received a task in this morning, so I create a branch from develop to implement this task:

```
git checkout -b task1 develop
```

To implement the task1, I need to add some other files into my project, and modify some files.
In the afternoon, my team leader asked me to do the task2, because the task2 is more urgent. So in the folder "**myproject"**, I create another branch "task2" from develop, and switch from task1 to task2.

```
git checkout -b task2 develop
```

What I expected is when I am on the task2 branch, all files I created on task1 branch must be disappeared. However, they are still there.

What is the best practice to implement several tasks (on different branches) in the same folder (**myproject**) ?

Comment: Have you committed them before `git checkout -b task2 develop`? Likely, no.

Comment: use: `git checkout task1; git add <new _and_ changed files>; git commit -m "Some incomplete work"; git checkout task2`.

Comment: Yes, I do "git checkout -b task2 develop"

Comment: But do you commit?  That's the important part.  The only benefit to creating multiple branches is if you commit the work to those branches.

Comment: You also may consider `git stash` to (temporarily) move uncommitted changes to a special place, called stash (actually it's a couple of specially marked commits) which can be easily revived later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this tutorial](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Getting-a-Git-Repository), it begins from simple use-cases.

Basically before switching to a new branch you should examine your work tree for uncommitted changes and commit them first. Use [git add](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add) with subsequent [git commit](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit). You also may find `git add --interactive`, `git commit --all` and [`git stash`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) useful (or use GUI tools like `git gui`).